# Echo Acf color picker into a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode

So am using ACF to make a theme color code to echo it in Emails backgrounds and pages backgrounds, using a simple text field.

What I did is I made this snippet:

```
add_shortcode( 'bg-color', function() {return'<?php the_field('color-code', 'option'); ?>';} );
```

To echo the text field as: #ffffff

But instead am getting a php error.

When I try using shortcode plugin, it works like a charm, but when I put it as the color field, it will return the exact name of the shortcode and not the actual color code, so it would look like this: `page-bacground: [bg-color]`, instead of `page-bacground: #fffff`

I know am doing something wrong in the first shortcode, as its a php withen a php, and thats why there is a **syntax error**.

I have also tried:

```
add_shortcode( 'bg-color', function() {return'[acf field="color-code" post_id="options"]';} );
```

But no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `get_field` since it returns the value like so:

```
add_shortcode('bg-color', function() {
    return get_field('color-code', 'option');
});

// PHP 7.4+ one liner for this simple case...
add_shortcode('bg-color', fn() => get_field('color-code', 'option'));
```

Comment: Great happy to hear it!